# Import entries from more than one file

Tags: plugin-feedme, import, feed

I am developing a property listing website that imports properties from XML files (i.e there is one XML file for each property). Is there any way that we can do an import from more than one file using FeedMe plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way out-of-the-box so your only options would be to either create a module that passes multiple XML files into feed me using the [direct feed url](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/trigger-import-via-cron.html) or to create a script/use software that merges all the files into one.

Comment: The number of feeds may grow in future to thousands so I don't think these will be better solution.